Acceso a una url con login desde react
estoy intentando que al pulsar un botón desde mi página de React, vaya a este enlace https://intranet.ffmadrid.es/nfg/NPcd/NFG_VisCalendario_Vis?cod_primaria=1000128&codgrupo=17145727&codcompeticion=17145693&codtemporada=19&codjornada=26&cod_agrupacion=&CDetalle=1 que me descarga un excel de datos, sin embargo, al dar a ese enlace te pide un acceso. Yo tengo credenciales pero no sé cómo hacer para capturar los campos e indicarle el nombre y contraseña desde mi aplicación y así poder descargar el documentos automáticamente
